# While loop doesn´t go through all times

Tags: loops, kotlin, while-loop

I have a problem with a while-loop in kotlin.
The task i have to solve is to encode a binary-string in to a pseudo-string.
I've written a function that is supposed to receive and encode the binary string like "1000011" (7-bit) into "0 0 00 0000 0 00" in this case.

```
fun doEncode (input : String) : String {
    var input = input
    var result : MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    var mOneActive = 0
    var mNullActive = 0
    var mNullCount = 0
    var mOneCount = 0
    var mIndexInput = 0
    var mRangeInput = input.length-1
    
    for (range in 0 until mRangeInput) {

        while (input[mIndexInput] == '0' && mIndexInput < mRangeInput) {
            mNullActive = 1
            mNullCount += 1
            mIndexInput += 1
        }
        if (mNullActive == 1) {
            result.add("00")
            result.add(" ")
            for(range in 0 until mNullCount) {
               result.add("0") 
            }
            result.add(" ")
            mNullActive = 0
            mNullCount = 0
        }

        while (input[mIndexInput] == '1' && mIndexInput < mRangeInput) {
            mOneActive = 1
            mOneCount += 1
            mIndexInput += 1
        }
        if (mOneActive == 1) {
            result.add("0")
            result.add(" ")
            for(range in 0 until mOneCount) {
               result.add("0") 
            }
            result.add(" ")
            mOneActive = 0
            mOneCount = 0
        }
    }

    var output = result.reduce { i, value -> i + value }     

    return output
}
```

But the function only encode the first 6 bit of the binary-string. The last on is missing.
I don´t see the mistake. When i increase the range (var mRangeInput) i get a "outofboundsexeption".
I have no further idea, so any help is welcome.

Comment: Side note: the prefix `m` for a variable is called Hungarian notation. It is used to indicate when a variable is a *member* variable. You have used it for local variables, so your variable names are self-contradictory. Anecdotally, most programmers seem to dislike Hungarian notation style because it makes code look more noisy and is redundant to IDE highlighting. But among the reasons some people use it is for reading code outside the IDE more easily and making autocomplete more helpful when you want to find a member.

Comment: thanks. i use it because i seen it on a online-course and there was no talk about the notification. but i look for more information on web.

Comment: Hungarian notation started from a good idea: encoding information that _couldn't_ fit into the type system.  Unfortunately, most people use it wrongly, in a way that adds little other than visual noise, and can get out-of-date.  (And as type systems get more expressive, the need for it reduces anyway.)  See [Joel Spolsky's authoritative explanation](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at these two lines.

```
var mRangeInput = input.length-1

for (range in 0 until mRangeInput) {
```

`mRangeInput` is the input length minus one. And `until` creates a range with an exclusive end. You have to choose one way or the other to exclude the final value of the range from 0 to the size, but you've done it both ways, so you've excluded one too many.

I didn't check anything else in your code. I don't know what the encoding is supposed to be.

Comment: thank you for your help. i found the mistake. tha annotation about "-1" and "until" was correct. but i alsways get the "IndexOutofboundsexeption". i go through the code step by step and when i increase "var mIndexInput = 0" with "+=1" i received "7" at the end of the while-loop. and then the while-loop first checked with its boolean "(input[mIndexInput] == '1' && mIndexInput < mRangeInput)" if "input[7] == '1'" is true, but "index[7]" is out of range. now when i change the boolean to "(mIndexInput < mRangeInput && input[mIndexInput] == '1')" the funktion wook fine.